# TypeConverter not working with ExpandoObject and DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, typeconverter, expandoobject

I have a `Poco` class where one Property is an enumeration type.
In order to make the enumeration property localizable on the UI layer (WPF) I have created a `TypeConverter` for the enumeration type which looks up the localized enumeration value.
A list of instances of this POCO class is bound to a WPF DataGrid:

```
// in the ViewModel:
public Pocos = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView( DataLayer.GetPocos() );
```

That worked perfectly well.

Later I refactored the code so that the data layer no longer returns `List<Poco>` but `List<ExpandoObject>`:

```
public Pocos = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView( DataLayer.GetExpandos() );
```

These `ExpandoObjects` are the result of database query and contain only a subset of the original `Poco's` properties, depending on the select statement.

Everything works fine, with the exception of the `TypeConverter` for the enumeration property which is no longer invoked.

The TypeConverter is still exposed, so this works:

```
dynamic eo = new ExpandoObject();
eo.EnumProperty = MyEnum.SomeValue;
var converter = TypeConverter.GetConverter( (eo.EnumProperty).GetType() );
var result = converter.ConvertTo( eo.EnumProperty, typeof( string ) );
```

I do not know what is going on inside WPF's DataGrid. I am under the impression that it, for whatever reason, simply invokes `ToString()` on the enumeration type property instead of invoking the `TypeConverter`.

Any way to get this working?

**Implementation Details:**

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PocoGrid" x:FieldModifier="public"  
  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
  ItemsSource="{Binding Pocos}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPoco}"
  bh:DataGridColumnsBehavior.BindableColumns="{Binding PocoColumns}"
  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.InputBindings>
    <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" Command="{Binding PocoDoubleClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding Pocos/}"/>
  </DataGrid.InputBindings>
</DataGrid>
```

TYPE CONVERTER:

```
public abstract class EnumTypeConverterBase : TypeConverter
{
   public static ILocalizedResourceProvider ResourceProvider { get; set; } = null;
}

public class EnumTypeConverter<T> : EnumTypeConverterBase where T : struct, IConvertible, IComparable
{
   private static string typeParameterName = typeof(T).Name;

   public override bool CanConvertFrom( ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType )
   {
      if( sourceType == typeof( string ) )
         return true;
      return base.CanConvertFrom( context, sourceType );
   }

   public override object ConvertFrom( ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value )
   {
      throw new NotImplementedException();
   }

   public override object ConvertTo( ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType )
   {
      string val = value.ToString();

      if( ResourceProvider == null )
         return val;
      else
         return ResourceProvider.GetEnum( typeParameterName, val );
   }
}
```

ENUMERATION DEFINITION:

```
[TypeConverter( typeof( EnumTypeConverter<MyEnum> ) )]
public enum MyEnum
{
   Unknown = 0,
   SomeValue = 1,
   SomeOtherValue = 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use a value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx). That's a more conventional way to do this anyhow, and it doesn't depend on reflection to get invoked at runtime.

```
public class MyEnumLocalizationConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var e = (MyEnum)value;

        var converted = "";

        //  Do whatever the type converter now does

        return converted;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- ... -->

    <local:MyEnumLocalizationConverter x:Key="MyEnumLocalizer" />

    <!-- ... -->
</Window.Resources>

<!-- ... -->

    <DataGridTextColumn
        Binding="{Binding EnumProperty, Converter={StaticResource MyEnumLocalizer}}"
        />
```

If you share some XAML I can show you

Comment: I added some implementation details, including the XAML. I am not sure whether the ValueConvert would work for my case. The implementation contains duzends of enumerations and the valueconverter appears to be specific to a single type. Is it possible to define a generic version?

Comment: @c__k You could keep the type converters and write a general value converter that uses reflection to get the correct type converter. I think that's the essence of what XAML was doing for you previously with the type converters, when it had a typed property as a binding source.

Comment: I tried to get that working for a couple of hours but eventually gave up. Problem was that I would have had to bind the converter to all columns because the column and its name where the enumeration type might occur is not know at compile time. I ended up creating a type at runtime and using this instead of the ExpandoObject.

Comment: @c__k Right, I didn't think it that far through. Creating a type at runtime! Wow.